# How to create a view for comments? Facebook like comments implemented (ruby on rails)

Tags: css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I implemented a facebook like comments on my page but I am trying to figure out how to get the view working.

Here's the code for how the comment works:

Comment controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
     def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.micropost = @micropost
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
       redirect_to(:back)
    else
      render 'shared/_comment_form'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment form view

```
<%= form_for([micropost, @comment]) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :comment_content %>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">
    Comment
  </button>
<% end %>
```

And I'm trying to figure out how to best display these comments after being submitted. Can I use this to build the view??

comment.html.erb

```
  <%= simple_format(comment.content) %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Ideally, I would like to get the comment to show just like how it is on this page that I'm using right now

Comment: you need to use javascript http://wowkhmer.com/2011/09/19/unobtrusive-ajax-with-rails-31/ if you use Rails 3.2 or Rails 4 http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
     def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.micropost = @micropost
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
       flag = true
    else
      flag = false
    end

respond_to do |format|
 format.html {flag ? redirect_to(:back) : render 'shared/_comment_form'}
format.js
end

  end
end
```

change your form to be ajaxified

```
<%= form_for([micropost, @comment], remote: true) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :comment_content %>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">
    Comment
  </button>
<% end %>
```

then edit your view a bit

comments/comment.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: {comment: @comment} %>
```

and the partial will be

_comment.html.erb

```
<div id="comment-<%= comment.id%>">
<%= simple_format(comment.content) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

then in comments/create.js.erb do

```
$("#comments_container").prepend(' <%=j render partial: "comments/comment", locals: {comment: @comment} %>');
```

instead of prepend you can do any kind of animations you want. you can append also, depending how you want to have your comments sorted

note I am using jQuery for this. #comments_container is the div where you want to put the comments

note that create.js.erb is basically the js view for the create action in comments controller so it can access any variable that the create action has

note2: I am using ruby 1.9 hash format

note3: I named the comment `#comment-<%= comment.id %>` so you can access it later if you want to delete it or work on it some other way, for example

```
def destroy

@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
format.js
end
end
```

and then in destroy.js.erb do

```
$("#comment-<%= @comment.id %>").remove();
```

which will delete that div

make sure to have jquery_ujs and jquery gem/files and that's pretty much it..